# How do I get Rocket.Chat to trust my company's root CA certificate?

Tags: node.js, meteor, rocket.chat

In order to create an outgoing WebHook, I need to trust my company's root CA certificate, which is inserted into all traffic going through our network.

I have tried everything as I described in the following issue that I logged:

https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/11546

This involved mainly trying both NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS and CAFILE (the latter being a suggestion from Meteor) environment variables, by using service config override. I can confirm the environment variables are set in the running processes for the Rocket.Chat service, but they have no effect.

(Not that I think it makes a difference, but I am running Rocket.Chat from the snap. I followed advice given here to add the environment variables to the service processes:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/declaratively-defining-environment-variables/175/26)

Comment: Which version of node are you using ?